# Messagebox appearing behind GXT Window -GWT

Tags: gwt, gxt

Messagebox appearing behind GXT window.
    after window.show() only message box is appearing.I need message box 
    appearing before window.show().

thanks 
i am gettig messagebox bottom of the window

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbWUz.png

Comment: could you provide some more details, please?

Comment: on click on hyperlink i am calling an widget class which has the code to write the data in to the gxt-Window and it has window.show().I need a MessageBox to show before window.show(),my problem is at a time both MessageBox and window are opening.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show popup windows sequentially you'll have to chain the windows show methods. It appears that you want to show the window once the MessageBox is closed. Have in mind that MessageBox methods that create dialog boxes (info, confirm, etc) do not wait box the box to be closed. window.show() does not wait either.
What you have to do is to open the window once the MessageBox is closed. Most of the MessageBox creation methods have a version that accepts a callback which will be triggered when a user clicks message box buttons. See the example below:

```
MessageBox.prompt("My Dialog Box", "Do you want to continue?", false,
      new Listener<MessageBoxEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(MessageBoxEvent event) {
                if (event.getButtonClicked().getItemId().equals(Dialog.OK)) {
                    window.show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.but my problem is not solved.As i need a MessageBox which showing progress as loading,until the window popup open.popup will take time to open  if it has more records to render into it.

Comment: @swamy, could you post some example code, please?
How do you close the progress messageBox and how do you know when to close it?

Comment: s that is true i am not able to figure out as i am not making any async call.simply i am calling messagebox before invoking a widget

Comment: Does this mean the progress bar should be displayed until the window is fully rendered?

Comment: And does it really take long to render it? I mean, is it long enough to show the progress bar to the user? Is this just client-code, no backend calss made?

Comment: If there are more than 1000 records it takes 2min to render.s it is cliend side code.nothing backend work- Marek

Comment: one more info in that widget class i am creating Grid and populating data and i am adding that grid to window.(for more clarifiaction i am adding that grid to horizontalpanel and that panel to vertical panel and at last window to vertical panel.)then window.show().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16414/discussion-between-marek-dec-and-swamy)

Comment: sorry @Marek the chat is disabled

Comment: Hmm, anyhow this should not take so long. It's probably because of the fact you create a huge DOM tree
you think I'd be possible to do something similiar to what a LiveGridView does?
I mean, to render just the visible part of the data
and paint more as this is scrolled down and at the same time destroy what is not visible?
maybe you could take advantage of the LiveGridView directly, and that would make things much faster

Comment: i am loading data from the livegrid only.but I am creating table using Grid-GWT

Comment: I guess that replacing this with a livegrid would provide you with a great improvement in the perfromance. In acy case, you could also try adding a custom component at the very end of your grid, that would close the progress dialog when rendered (in onRender method). Don't really know if this would work, you'd have to make a quick test.